# How to remove tab space in SnowSQL without removing whitespaces?

Tags: sql, replace, tabs, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm very new to SnowSQL and I'm trying to execute this simple command removing tab spaces from the string.

```
SELECT REPLACE('abcd         xyz      efgh   pqrs  -3','   ','') AS tabs_havebeen_replaced;
```

It does replace the tab space perfectly, and leaves the two whitespaces before -3 too. But the problem arises when I add one more whitespace before the -3. It considers those the 3 consecutive whitespaces as a tab space and removes it.

I tried using '\t' and CHAR(9) but it did not change a thing. When I literally use the tab space between the quotes, it works. (**I suspect the command considers every 3 consecutive whitespaces as tab space and replaces it with null and that's why the spaces before -3 is left out when it is 2 and gets removed when it is 3**).

Could anyone please suggest some work around to how tab space is replaceable without replacing singular whitespaces too?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\t` doesn't work because you actually don't have any tab space in your text, you just have multiple whitespaces. Thus you should either generate a text that actually includes tab spaces, or specify in which cases you don't want a sequence of 3 spaces to be replaced with an empty string.

Comment: I did use the tab key in my keyboard to create seperation between the letters, so I'm not sure why it considers it as multiple whitespaces.

Comment: It may depend on the editor that you're using. Try copy-pasting the following character " ".